# pages aren't fully generated after moving joomla site

Tags: joomla3.0

I need to move our site to another provider because of stability issues. I tried several things:
- let installatron copy it from the current (old) tot the new server,
- installing a fresh joomla, copying templates etc, importing database.

It doesn't matter which way i do it the result stays the same. The site appears to be right, but the footer isn't fully loaded. The 'go to top' button dissappeared to.

The current (soon to be moved) site is: http://hang-on-run.nl/
The preview of the new hosting is: http://hang-on-run.nl.alvast-online.nl/

If you scroll to the end you see that the current site has got a full footer and a 'go to top' button. If you look at the preview site, this footer is hardly visible.

[image]

When you compare the source codes you clearly see that the page isn't fully generated. Somehow it stops generating the page.

[image]
All the other things work fine...

I really hope that someone knows how to fix this, the site has to go live next week :(.

Kind regards,
Mijno

Comment: Are there any errors in the error log ?

Comment: i can't see anything in the logfile... where can i find it or how do i turn in on?

Comment: You find the error log on the web server. Any hosting company gives you somehow access to it. Either through ftp or in the administration panel.

Answer (score 0):

so i tried to view your site anonymously and your site looks fine that way. i believe this could be ISP issue. Something got to do with your router. i myself am not very aware of how to fix this problem but will try to get an answer. meanwhile go to 
http://anonymouse.org/anonwww.html link
put your url in the blank provided and you will see the desired result
http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://hang-on-run.nl.alvast-online.nl/
cheers

Comment: okay here is one thing you can try to do
copy your host to another location and delete the one in C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC just as a test
you can restore if it didn't work else reset the host file to the default. 
follow the below link to do so
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034

Comment: I'm not the only one who does see this fault. Everyone in our team (4 people) with different systems see it. When you browse anonymous the page gets additional code (the layer from anonymous for instance). With this additional layers the site works fine. But without it...